# Using distinct on a column while getting multiple column data

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My Database Table structure:

```
Schema  Property  Type
```

For different 'Schema' values I have same 'Property' and 'Type' values.

My linq query:

```
IEnumerable<CModel> model = db.dbModels.AsEnumerable().Select(o => new CModel { CName = "XXX", PName = o.Property, PType = o.Type }).Distinct().ToList();
```

What I'm trying to do is get distinct 'Property' and 'Type' values but the query is giving me duplicate values.

Thanks

Comment: What are the date types of `Property` and `Type`? If they are simple types like string or int this query should produce distinct results. And what's the use of this `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: @GertArnold  data types are string, Removing ASEnumerable solved the problem..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group them:

```
IEnumerable<CModel> model = db.dbModels.AsEnumerable()
                            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Property, x.Type })
                            .Select(x => new CModel 
                                        { CName = "XXX", 
                                          PName = x.Property, 
                                          PType = x.Type }).ToList();
```